# Shakespearean equivalent of genuinely?

Tags: translation, shakespeare

What would the word 'genuinely' 
as in: 'genuinely I am being really funny'
be in early modern english, of Shakespeare era? ?

Comment: 'truly' usually works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[verily](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/verily)**

> ADVERB
>
> *archaic.*  Truly; certainly
>
> example: *verily these men are mad*